# Add querystring value to preview URL

Tags: sitecore-client

I thought I had an approach for this but it does not work. My new process is never called. I just need to add an additional querystring to any preview URL that is generated in CM (publish preview, presentation preview, preview site, experience manager) I thought I could just add it to this pipeline.

```
    <getPagePreviewUrl>
      <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPagePreviewUrl.GetDefaultUrlOptions, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
      <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPagePreviewUrl.SetLanguage, Sitecore.Kernel"/>              
      <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPagePreviewUrl.GetUrl, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
      <processor type="MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly" patch:source="MyConfig.config"/>      
    </getPagePreviewUrl>
```

My class looks like this:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        /// <summary>Runs the processor.</summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        public void Process(GetPagePreviewUrlArgs args)
        {
        }
    }
```

However, my new process is never called (not logging, can't attached). I have looked at the showconfigs and it is patched in where I expected it to be (as shown above). Is this not the correct pipeline?

**Update**
Been digging into this and based on what I have found all the previews are command based (would make sense). So to tweak the behavior you need to override the following commands.

```
    <command name="item:preview" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.PreviewItem,Sitecore.Kernel"/>

    <command name="contenteditor:preview" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ContentEditor.Preview,Sitecore.Kernel"/>

    <command name="webedit:openexperienceeditor" type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.OpenExperienceEditor, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config"/>
```

Headed down that road and will update.